# Excel array formula that returns columns headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem I am having is given an excel table:

Spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet-screenshot]

I am using an active X control box to select a name from `column 1` (It is linked to a cell), and then I am trying to use an `INDEX`, `SMALL`, `IF` formula in order to search that particular row for all instances of `yes` and return that column header(language) into a list box.

So if I were to select `John` from the control box, the list box would fill with `English`, `Spanish`, and `French`. If I were to select `Alvin` the list box would fill with `Spanish`.

I am running into a wall here as everything I can find on the subject deals with `ROW` and what few `COLUMN` questions I do find are vague.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table is in A1:E8 and the active X control box is located @ I1, put these in any other cell put this formula (broken down for clarity) :

```
=IF(LEFT(INDEX((OFFSET($B$2:$E$2,MATCH($I$1,$A$2:$A$8,0)-1,0)="Yes")&($B$1:$E$1),1),4)="TRUE",INDEX($B$1:$E$1,1)&" ","")&

IF(LEFT(INDEX((OFFSET($B$2:$E$2,MATCH($I$1,$A$2:$A$8,0)-1,0)="Yes")&($B$1:$E$1),2),4)="TRUE",INDEX($B$1:$E$1,2)&" ","")&

IF(LEFT(INDEX((OFFSET($B$2:$E$2,MATCH($I$1,$A$2:$A$8,0)-1,0)="Yes")&($B$1:$E$1),3),4)="TRUE",INDEX($B$1:$E$1,3)&" ","")&

IF(LEFT(INDEX((OFFSET($B$2:$E$2,MATCH($I$1,$A$2:$A$8,0)-1,0)="Yes")&($B$1:$E$1),4),4)="TRUE",INDEX($B$1:$E$1,4),"")
```

Idea : use offset to define which row to 'read' the Yes. combine the string. if true is detected, print, else blank.

please share if it works/not. (^_^)